# Is there a way to seperate templates and view models completely with knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, viewmodel

What I am looking for is to have a way of implementing a template where the template only knows an interface of a view model.

Let's say that I have a view called Greetings. It knows that it can communicate with an interface called IGreetingsVM.

The IGreetingsVM can look something like:

```
interface IGreetingsVM {
    greetings: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}
```

In the actual view model I implement the interface:

```
class GreetingsVMImpl implements IGreetingsVM {
    greetings: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.greetings("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Since the template knows it got an IGreetingsVM, it also knows that it can call greetings, so:

```
<p data-bind="text: greetings"></p>
```

In this way, I can separate the whole view from an actual view model implementation.

However, in most examples I've seen, they usually say that this template must have this viewmodel implementation.

This can be achieved in example Java where you have a code behind file for each form you create where you can have a get and set method for the view model.

Example:

```
public class Greeter extends JPanel {
    public static final string PROP_VIEWMODEL = "viewModel";

    private IGreetingsVM viewModel;
    private JLabel greetingLabel;
    private BindingGroup bindingGroup;

    public Greeter() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void setViewModel(IGreetingsVM viewModel) {
        IGreetingsVM oldViewModel = this.viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_VIEWMODEL, oldViewModel, viewModel);
    }

    public IGreetingsVM getViewModel() {
        return this.viewModel;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new BindingGroup();

        greetingLabel = new JLabel();

        Binding binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(
            AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, 
            this,
            ELProperty.create("${viewModel.greetings}"), 
            greetingLabel,
            BeanProperty.create("text"));

        // similar to knockout where bindings auto update components.
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve ^ in javascript, maybe preferably with knockout?

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is much, much looser than Java, and doesn't have or need the concept of *interfaces*. (*We* may need the concept for design purposes, I'm just saying that the language doesn't.) You just provide an object that has the necessary properties.

So in client-side JavaScript using KO, all you have to do is ensure that the viewModel you give KO has a `greetings` property, ideally as an observable:

```js
// Three different VMs
var vm1 = {
  greetings: ko.observable("Hello from #1")
};
var vm2 = {
  greetings: ko.observable("Hello from #2"),
  someOtherThing: ko.observable("Something else")
};
var vm3 = {
  greetings: ko.observable("Hello from #3"),
  different: ko.observable("And now for something completely different")
};

// Note how neither KO nor JavaScript cares that the models are different:
ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById("ex1"));
ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById("ex2"));
ko.applyBindings(vm3, document.getElementById("ex3"));
```

```html
<!-- Three "instances" of your template: -->
<div id="ex1">
  <span data-bind="text: greetings"></span>
</div>
<div id="ex2">
  <span data-bind="text: greetings"></span>
</div>
<div id="ex3">
  <span data-bind="text: greetings"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```